# Angular dom manupulation not working as expected

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, dom

I have a set of check boxes using the array as follows:

```
 <div *ngFor="let order of orders; let i = index">
    <input type="checkbox" id="{{orders[i].name}}_i">{{orders[i].name}}
  </div>
```

Lets suppose check boxes with id's order1, order2 ....etc

What I need I want to change check boxes make it checked/unchecked using id's or any other mechanism something like the follows:

```
document.getElementById("order1").checked = true;
```

I have tried it, but it is not working and shows errors.

on my research i have saw an option `@ViewChild`. But for that I need to declare it first what I have is id can be any it can not be predefined it can be any. please suggest me a mechanism...

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to use JavaScript? Since you are in an Angular and TypeScript context, you could use the Angular Two-Way binding to achieve what you want to do.

You could add a `checked` property to your "order" model and then bind this `checked` property to the checkbox input `ngModel`.

#### order.ts

```
export class Order {
  public name: string;
  public checked: boolean;
  ...
}
```

#### component.ts

```
@Component(...)
export class MyComponent {
  public orders: Array<Order>; // Initialize with ngOnInit hook or any other way.
}
```

#### component.html

```html
<div *ngFor="let order of orders; let i = index">
    <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="order.checked">{{order.name}}
</div>
```

> Note that you don't really need to use the `orders[i]` syntax to access the current object since you already have the `order` variable that represents the current order in the loop. More informations on Angular's website: https://angular.io/guide/displaying-data#showing-an-array-property-with-ngfor

Now if you want to control the checked state of your items, you can simply change the `checked` value of any of your `Order` objects and it will be automatically updated on your interface:

```
@Component(...)
export class MyComponent {
  public orders: Array<Order>; 

  public checkFirstOrder(): void {
    this.orders[0].checked = true;
  }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Actually I have checkboxes in angular material tree and what I need is something just want to make it checked using id or name.

Comment: I think it should work even if you are using checkboxes in an angular material tree. You are still looping on an array of objects, so the two-way binding should work as expected.